# Arrays comparison - argument lists

Tags: java

I am trying to get user input of two arrays and compare them, here are snippets of my code after I take user input of the arrays size:

```
        String[] words = new String[size];

        for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Insert a word: ");
            words[i] = input.next();
        }

        String[] words2 = new String[size2];

        for (j = 0; j < words2.length; j++){
            System.out.print("Insert a word: ");
            words2[j] = input.next();
        }

        boolean result= Arrays.equals(words, words2);
        System.out.print("Arrays are equal: " + result);
        }
    }
```

I have been looking at other questions to solve this error but I had no success.

```
Method equals in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
 boolean result= Arrays.equals(words, words2);
  required: Object
  found: String[],String[]
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: You probably defined a variable named `Arrays`, and are thus calling equals() on this Arrays variable, instead of calling the static method java.util.Arrays.equals(). Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong here, @JBNizet is probably right, just try to remove import and use java.util.Arrays.equals()

Comment: @FilipRistic thank you so much, that solved my problem :)

Comment: Consider changing title, adding response, accepting response. Or deleting the question.